# Why does dragon fire from Game of Thrones leave bones?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Before the dragons from the TV series have grown we learned from the pyromancer that [wildfire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wildfire) was the closest they could get to dragon fire. According to him the wildfire could burn through metal, stone, and flesh.

We could also saw how dragon fire could destroy the keep leaving great big holes in the walls.

Later when Dany's dragons grew up and started hunting we could see that they ate goats and a poor child leaving nothing but burned bones behind. How come the bones were left if the fire is so strong?

Also, if the fire was that strong, how does Dany expect that a metal chain and a door could keep them?

Comment: You don't want to burn the meat to a cinder so the bones will not be desecrated.

Comment: How would them eat the prey if they were burn to the bones? The dragons probably just lightly toasted their food

Comment: Really, would you expect that dragons wouldn't have any control over their breath?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How come the bones were left if the fire is so strong?

You must bear in mind that we had no idea how exactly the bones came to be. **[Drogon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Drogon)** was said to have been responsible for them, but there are a few scenarios which this could have happened:

- he might have just been burning something nearby, or
- might have just devoured the carcass, passing the bones (which were scorched due to the insides of the dragon being extremely hot, or
- the bones might have been cooked in an oven as suspected by Dany (for the sheep anyway)

> Also, if the fire was that strong, how does Dany expect that a metal chain and a door could keep them?

**Chains Were Made to be Broken**
The metal chains were only truly to get the dragons *into* the pit, beyond that there was no guarantee that the chains would hold. In fact, **[Viserion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Viserion)** had actually broken through his:

<sup>[*A Dance With Dragons* spoiler]</sup>

> The dragons craned their necks around, gazing at them with burning eyes. Viserion had shattered one chain and melted the others. He clung to the roof of the pit like some huge white bat, his claws dug deep into the burnt and crumbling bricks. [**Rhaegal**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaegal), still chained, was gnawing on  the carcass of a bull. The bones on the floor of the pit were deeper than the last time she had been down here, and the walls and floors were black and grey, more ash than brick. They would not hold much longer … but behind them was only earth and stone. Can dragons tunnel through rock, like the firewyrms of old Valyria? She hoped not. 
> <sup>*-A Song of Ice and Fire: A Dance With Dragons, Part Two - Blood and Fire (Daenerys).*</sup>

Perhaps given time, they *could* burn through the walls/doors (but that's just conjecture).
Take note also that there are a pile of bones. We don't know if they are scorched or not, but that definitely shows that an encounter with a dragon **can** leave bones behind!

**The Blood of Old Valyria**
There are some whom the dragons might take a liking to, or at least tolerate:

<sup>[*A Dance With Dragons* spoiler]</sup>

> [**Brown Ben Plumm**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ben_Plumm) is one such person; he can trace his ancestry back to Old Valyria, and there are many mentions of how the dragons took a liking to him, especially this one: 
> [Tyrion:] Your branch sprouted from a stone spit across the narrow sea, no doubt. A younger son of Viserys Plumm, I’d wager. The queen’s dragons were fond of you, were they not?”
> That seemed to amuse the sellsword. [Plumm:]“Who told you that?” 
> [Tyrion:]“No one. Most of the stories you hear about dragons are fodder for fools. Talking dragons, dragons hoarding gold and gems, dragons with four legs and bellies big as elephants, dragons riddling with sphinxes … nonsense, all of it. But there are truths in the old books as well. Not only do I know that the queen’s dragons took to you, but I know why.” 
> [Plumm:]“My mother said my father had a drop of dragon blood.”
> <sup>*-A Song of Ice and Fire: A Dance With Dragons, Part Two - Blood and Fire (Tyrion).*</sup>

Using this to one's advantage can help to provide a means for controlling dragons.

Answer (score 19):

To melt castles, it probably requires a sustained stream of a lot of flame. Remember, Balerion was a huge dragon.

Whereas for killing goats/children, it'd be more a light roasting.

No doubt that the dragons could burn through the chains.

> You saw them do this at the end of season 2

So Daenerys is probably relying on the dragons not figuring out to do this.

Comment: Or: *magic* chains.

Comment: Then again, they're still juvenile dragons. They can't be ridden yet, let alone mimic the great Balerion the Dread. Maybe their fire isn't strong enough yet.

Comment: This answer.  They burn the goats and children because they want to eat them.  If they burn them long enough to incinerate bones, there's nothing to eat.

Answer (score 7):

Since I agree with dwjohnston's answer regarding the remaining bones, I'd like to pick up that second question regarding chains.

While I still haven't watched the series that far (yeah, yeah, just a lack of time :(), I'd assume it's essentially similar to how you train a dog:

Most dogs wouldn't have any issue chewing off their leash (at least as long as it's made of leather or some kind of linen).

Yet they typically don't do it, since you somehow taught them not to do it.

Why wouldn't you be able to  get a dragon to do the same thing? After all you can't take them for a walk on some big chain anyway, so you'll need some form of control over them, which (to me) implies, that you could get them to respect the chains or other restraints.

Oh, and if they're able to melt through solid stone, I wouldn't worry about my castle door... :)

Comment: "They're dragons, Khaleesi, they can never be tamed. Not even by their mother."
―Ser Jorah to Daenerys

Comment: @Yossi: Ser Friendzone just hasn’t seen *How to Train Your Dragon*.

Comment: Even the most dangerous and untameable wild animals can learn not to hurt the nice human who feeds them regularly and maintains their living quarters.  I think it's entirely plausible that Dany's dragons don't escape because they don't *want* to escape.  (So far, anyway.)

Comment: Well, in the HBO episode at least the two chained dragons were *not* happy and certainly behaved as if they were surprised at finding themselves chained and left behind. They totally want to escape and if they don't it will be simply because the story was (re)written that way. It wouldn't be the first plot-hole in that series ya know ;^)

Comment: @user23715 I haven't been watching the TV series, and I decided after *A Feast for Crows* that I wasn't going to read any more doorstops until it was *done,* so I didn't know that happened.  Seems like a really foolish idea!

Comment: @Zack Foolish, yes. Dany hasn't been terribly long on wisdom with any of her decisions so far.

Comment: "Taming" and getting some animal not to do something are two different things. To add another dog equivalent: A dog who wants to get away from whatever its leash is attached to, will most likely pull away, yet it won't necessarilly try to bite off the leash, even if that would be the most logical way of escaping. Simply knowing what you're able to do or what's keeping you from doing what you want to do are one thing. Combining this knowledge to solve a problem is something different and maybe the dragons are just too dumb to do it. But I'd guess it would be natural for them to try their fire.