# Shouldn't the Dragons take action?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Rhaegal and Viserion never took action to escape from where Daenerys locked them, they could easily melt the chains as we have seen before on the show.

> And who ends up breaking free both is Tyrion

Is there a reason for that?

Comment: have we seen dragons melt chains on the show (or read it in the books) before? please remind me when... I cannot recall that ever occurring.

Comment: [Related](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60933/21267)

Comment: I might be wrong, but shouldnt the question title be a bit more specific? I don't think it's a spoiler to mention the dragons melting their chains.

Comment: @Theyna https://youtu.be/KMvzfPDM3m0

Comment: @AerisFang I could be more specific on the question, but the stone on the door could be melted with enough heat aswell

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you say "as we have seen before on the show" you are likely referring to Season 2 in the House of the Undying:

The popular consensus here is that those chains were magical in nature, which is supported by the fact that the dragons did not melt them until the [death of Pyat Pree](https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-Daenerys-2-chained-dragons-burn-the-chains-down-and-get-themselves-free-if-dragons-breathe-fire) (the necromancer).

Furthermore, you should know in the books the Dragons were not set free manually, but instead broke free of their chains after using their breath to weaken (but not fully melt) the steel:

> Viserion. Yes. Where is Viserion? The prince lowered his torch to throw some light into the gloom below. He could see the green dragon ripping at the smoking carcass of the sheep, his long tail lashing from side to side as he ate. A thick iron collar was visible about his neck, with three feet of **broken** chain dangling from it. Shattered links were strewn across the floor of the pit amongst the blackened bones—twists of metal, partly melted.

Regarding the characteristics of dragons, The Princess and The Queen, or, The Blacks and The Greens is a novella edited in part by George R. R. Martin.  It contains supplemental material for the world of Westeros and claims that it takes a fully grown dragon to melt steel and stone:

> At the same time, as the dragon grows older, its flames become hotter and fiercer. Where a hatchling's flame can set straw aflame, dragons, like Balerion and Vhagar in the fullness of their power, could melt steel and stone. It is said that dragons are fire made flesh.

[Source](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dragon#cite_note-Rtpatq.7B.7B.7B2.7D.7D.7D.7B.7B.7B3.7D.7D.7D-3)

From this information it can be safely inferred that the dragons are not meant to be quite old enough to "melt steel and stone" with their breath, and the scene in Season 2 can be chalked up to magical mechanisms.

Additionally, regarding the divergence: a viewer should consider the additional effect and trust that Tyrion releasing the dragons has likely generated, especially since he introduces himself as a friend of their mother.  It is a popular theory that Tyrion will eventually be the one [to create saddles for the dragons](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/1yvtio/spoilers_adwd_tyrion_saddlemaker/), and the show needed to establish rapport first so the eventual build up will make sense to show-only fans.

Comment: Very good! You're getting the hang of this. I edited your post to make the links more readable. Feel free to revert if I overstepped.

Comment: Thank you, I think I've finally found one of the few Stack Exchanges I have a chance at contributing to.  I'll next learn how to present cleaner and better formatted answers.

Answer (score 1):

RE: "As we've seen" - the Iron Throne was forged in such a fashion, however -

1) It was forged by the mightiest of dragons, and we know that subsequent generations of dragons, especially ones not allowed to roam free, became smaller and less formidable over time.  And these dragons are still young and developing.  If they will every be able to out and out melt steel, which is not a given, they might not be there yet.

2) The Iron Throne, itself, is not just a heap of molten steel that was reformed.  It still retains the basic shape of the swords, so how much melting occurs, vs softening is not clear, even from the mightiest of dragons.

3) Steel itself is initially melted in a forge, which traps and magnifies the heat.  It's possible that the heat of dragon fire, while very hot, might physically dissipate too much vs a dragon's ability to sustain the fire, which is not indefinite.

4) One unknown factor is the degree to which a dragon can withstand fire.  Of course they'd be somewhat resistant, one would assume, but are they completely immune?  If there was a dragon vs dragon fight, would their fire be useless against each other?  Remember, the shackles restrain them because they are attached to their limbs.  If they breathe fire to melt or weaken the shackles, they are also breathing that fire directly on their own limbs, and are heating themselves up along with the metal.

5) While dragons understand that fire is specifically a weapon that can be used against other creatures, do they understand steel and its relationship to heat, specifically?  I'm not sure to what levels their intelligence rises.